# Copy all files .doc or .docx in folder and subfolder into another folder

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to C++ and winapi, currently working on a project to create a winapi application with a function to copy all files .doc and .docx in one drive to another folder.
Below is what I have done and it doesn't seem to work:

Can anyone show me how to do this properly ?

```
void  cc(wstring inputstr) {
    TCHAR sizeDir[MAX_PATH];
    wstring search = inputstr + TEXT("\\*");
    wcscpy_s(sizeDir, MAX_PATH, search.c_str());

WIN32_FIND_DATA findfiledata;
HANDLE Find = FindFirstFile(sizeDir, &findfiledata);

do {

    if (findfiledata.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
        if (!wcscmp(findfiledata.cFileName, TEXT(".")) || !wcscmp(findfiledata.cFileName, TEXT(".."))) continue;
        //checking folder or file
        wstring dirfolder = inputstr + TEXT("\\") + findfiledata.cFileName;
        cc(dirfolder);
    }
    else {
        wstring FileSearch = findfiledata.cFileName;
        //.doc or docx
        if (!wcscmp(FileSearch.c_str(), L".doc") || !wcscmp(FileSearch.c_str(), L".docx")) {
            TCHAR src[256] = L"D:\\test\\";
            wstring dirsrc = inputstr + TEXT("\\") + findfiledata.cFileName;
            _tprintf(TEXT("  %s  \n"), dirsrc.c_str());
            wcscat_s(src, findfiledata.cFileName);
            CopyFile(dirsrc.c_str(), src, TRUE);
        }
    }

} while (FindNextFile(Find, &findfiledata) != 0); 
FindClose(Find);
}
```

The `inputstr` here when i call the function is the drive that i want to search like `cc(L"D:");`

Comment: Uh... what's wrong with [`find ... -exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that but this is an assignment that required me to code a winapi application with functionality like I described above, currently I'm stuck figuring out why it not working what went wrong :(

Comment: this kind of thing is actually easier now to do with std::filesystem if you can use C++17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!wcscmp(FileSearch.c_str(), L".doc") || !wcscmp(FileSearch.c_str(), L".docx"))
```

This is comparing the whole file name. We only need to compare the file extension. `PathFindExtension` can be used to find the file extension:

```
const wchar_t* ext = PathFindExtension(findfiledata.cFileName);
if (_wcsicmp(ext, L".doc") == 0 || _wcsicmp(ext, L".docx") == 0)
{
    const std::wstring path = inputstr + L"\\" + findfiledata.cFileName;
    std::wcout << path << '\n';
}
```

`findfiledata` should be zero initialized.

Adding `CopyFile` inside that recursive function may cause problems. Because `FindNextFile` could see the new copied file, and the function tries to copy it again.

You could instead save the result in a vector of strings, then copy the file once `cc` is finished.

```
void cc(const std::wstring &inputstr, std::vector<std::wstring> &vec)
{
    std::wstring wildcard{ inputstr + L"\\*" };
    WIN32_FIND_DATA find = { 0 };
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(wildcard.c_str(), &find);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
    do
    {
        if (find.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (!wcscmp(find.cFileName, L".") || !wcscmp(find.cFileName, L".."))
                continue;
            const std::wstring dir = inputstr + L"\\" + find.cFileName;
            cc(dir, vec);
        }
        else 
        {
            const wchar_t* ext = PathFindExtension(find.cFileName);
            if (_wcsicmp(ext, L".doc") == 0 || _wcsicmp(ext, L".docx") == 0)
            {
                const std::wstring path = inputstr + L"\\" + find.cFileName;
                vec.push_back(path);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(handle, &find) != 0);
    FindClose(handle);
}
```

Used as

```
std::vector<std::wstring> result;
cc(L"D:\\test", result);
for (const auto& e : result)
    std::wcout << e << '\n';
```

---

Note, [`PathFindExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensiona) requires additional headers and libraries. If it's not available for some reason, and [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is not available, here is a do it yourself method:

```
std::wstring test = findfiledata.cFileName;
auto dot = test.find_last_of(L'.');
if (dot != std::wstring::npos)
{
    auto ext = test.substr(dot);
    for (auto& e : ext) e = towlower(e);
    if (ext == L".doc" || ext == L".docx")
    {
        std::wstring path = inputstr + L"\\" + findfiledata.cFileName;
        std::wcout << path << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather then hunting down the extension manually, consider using [`PathFindExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensionw) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I forgot about that. Updated.